# Docker-compose with postgres with geography postgis not working

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, postgis

I am using a docker-compose container that runs a flask app. Within this container a postgres container is launched with the Postgis extension (the [mdillon/postgis](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/) image). Everything runs fine but a single Postgis extension (Geography) does not work, which I can not explain.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  flask:
    build: .
    entrypoint:
      - flask
      - run
      - --host=0.0.0.0
    environment:
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
      FLASK_APP: app.py
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      - './app:/app'
    networks:
      - db_net
  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis
    networks:
      - db_net

networks:
  db_net:
```

After running `sudo docker-compose up --build` it creates two containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                     NAMES
1836d3d15765        img_flask         "flask run --host=0.…"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   img_flask_1
b25752af45ad        mdillon/postgis     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       5432/tcp                                  img_db_1
```

When opening the flask app or db logs it claims the following:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) type "geography" does not exist
LINE 7:  geom geography(POINT,4326)
```

Checking postgis is correct and reinstalling it within the DB does not solve it. The packages are as follows:

```
                                            List of installed extensions
          Name          | Version |   Schema   |                             Description                             
------------------------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 fuzzystrmatch          | 1.1     | public     | determine similarities and distance between strings
 plpgsql                | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis                | 2.5.0   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
 postgis_tiger_geocoder | 2.5.0   | tiger      | PostGIS tiger geocoder and reverse geocoder
 postgis_topology       | 2.5.0   | topology   | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
(5 rows)
```

Summarising, my containers work fine and Postgis is well installed. But there is a problem when a query requests the Geography function. Is there anyone that can give advice on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Does the user running the query have public in the search_path in the session running the query?

Comment: @Jeremy; The search_path has public indeed: **`postgres=# SHOW search_path; `**
`search_path   
-----------------
 public
(1 row)`

Comment: Fixed, Accidentally working in a different db. @Jeremy thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, Accidentally working in a different db. @Jeremy thanks!